# What will come in place of?

Tags: pattern

> Refer to following diagram and tell what will come in place of two '?'
>
> [image]
>
> Note : An explanation is required about the pattern...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer is:

> G and 11

Reason:

> On each section, there are two alternating formats:
>
> A(1) Y(25) C(3) - 26
> E(5) U(21) ?(?) - 22
> I(9) Q(17) K(11) - 18
>
> X(24) D(4) V(22) - 3
> T(20) H(8) R(18) - 7
> P(16) L(12) N(14) - ?
>
> As you can see, with the first format, from the first letter to the third, the index of the letter is increased by 2.  Also, from the second letter to the number in the middle, the index is increased by 1.
> With the second format, the opposite is true (first and third letters are decreased by 2, second letter and middle number are decreased by 1).  With that, the missing values that satisfy the pattern are:
>
> E(5) U(21) G(7) - 22
> P(16) L(12) N(14) - 11

Comment: you said "K" as ans....sure about this ?

Comment: @user2408578 Yeah, I got myself confused between the letters and numbers for a minute there.

Comment: yep...nicely done...it exhibits ^ and V pattern with alternate left and right letters marked as digits...